# How to execute Selenium scripts on an already opened browser?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

The code below opens a new blank window.

How to execute Selenium scripts on an already opened browser?

```
Chrome Version 90.0.4430.72 (Official Build) (32-bit)
ChromeDriver 90.0.4430.24
```

and tried with version

```
Chrome version 100.0.4896.127
```

command line code:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application> chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222 -user-data-dir="D:\Programing\Programing App\chromedriver_win32\chromedata"`

Java code:

```
package selenium1;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class Chromeoptiontest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "D:\\Programing\\Programing App\\oldChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
        option.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(option);

    }

}
```

Comment: Using an already opened browser is not supported by selenium.

Comment: @Jortega is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***It's officially not supported.***

*However, there is some working code which claims to support this:*

https://web.archive.org/web/20171214043703/http://tarunlalwani.com/post/reusing-existing-browser-session-selenium-java/.

Answer (score 0):

1- Open CMD as administrator.
(I don't know if it works without administror way.)

2- Start Chrome via this code:

```
C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir="C:\Temp"
```

3- Now use below code to lunch:

C#:

```
{
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.DebuggerAddress = "127.0.0.1:9222";
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.Navigate.GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
}
```

VB.NET:

```
Dim options As ChromeOptions = New ChromeOptions
options.DebuggerAddress = "127.0.0.1:9222"
Dim driver As ChromeDriver = New ChromeDriver(options)
driver.Navigate.GoToUrl("http://www.google.com")
```