# Reusing same browser window in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently using Python and Selenium to loop my server for specific tasks to complete, I have tried to do 2 things, to speed up the process they are:

1. To use `options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir={script_directory}\\profile")` in the Chrome driver initiasation to avoid having to log in all the time.
2. To **try** and reuse the same browser window instead of closing and then re-opening the browser all the time.

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pathlib
import time
import urllib.parse

import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

USER = "..."
PASS = "..."


def upload_to_server(link, redirect, unique_hash):
    try:
        requests.get(
            "https://www.example.com/crons.php?cronUploadToServer=1&link={0}&redirect={1}&hash={2}".format(link,
                                                                                                                 redirect,
                                                                                                                 unique_hash))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


def download_from_server():
    try:
        server = requests.get("https://www.example.com/crons.php?cronDownloadFromServer=1")
        return server.text.strip()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


# tear down chrome.
def tear_down(_driver):
    _driver.quit()
    _driver.close()


def check_for_tasks():
    if download_from_server() == "NO_TASKS":
        print("--> NO TASKS")
    else:
        # init the chrome driver.
        def init_driver(using_linux, proxy):
            script_directory = pathlib.Path().absolute()
            try:
                options = Options()
                options.headless = False
                options.add_argument('start-maximized')
                options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')
                options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
                options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
                options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
                options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
                options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir={script_directory}\\profile")
                options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
                options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
                prefs = {'profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications': 2}
                options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)

                if proxy == "0.0.0.0:0":
                    print("--> PROXY DISABLED ...")
                else:
                    print("--> PROXY: " + str(proxy) + " ...")
                    options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy)
                if using_linux:
                    return webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
                else:
                    return webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

        # create session.
        driver = init_driver(False, "0.0.0.0:00")

        # starting URL.
        driver.get('https://www.example.com/logon')

        # click recorded.
        def topcashback_click(_driver):
            try:
                _driver.get('https://www.example.com/Earn.aspx?mpurl=shein&mpID=17233')
                if "redirect.aspx?mpurl=shein" in _driver.current_url:
                    return _driver.current_url
                else:
                    return False
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

        # already logged in check.
        if ">Account</span>" in driver.page_source:

            print("--> LOGGED IN (ALREADY) ...")
            driver.get('https://www.SITE.CO.UK/Earn.aspx?mpurl=shein&mpID=17233')

            try:

                server = download_from_server()
                data_from_server = server.split('|')

                link = topcashback_click(driver)
                print("--> LINK --> " + link)
                time.sleep(4)

                if link != driver.current_url:
                    print("--> LINK (REDIRECT) --> " + driver.current_url)
                    upload_to_server(urllib.parse.quote_plus(link),
                                     urllib.parse.quote_plus(
                                         driver.current_url.replace('https://www.example.com', data_from_server[0])),
                                     data_from_server[1])
                    # print(driver.current_url.replace('https://www.example.com', data_from_server[0]))
                    print("--> LINK UPLOADED TO THE DB ...")
                    # tear_down(driver)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

        else:

            # TopCashBack login for the first time.
            def topcashback_login(_driver):
                _driver.get('https://www.example.com/logon')
                # small sleep to let the page load.
                time.sleep(1)
                _driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="txtEmail"]').send_keys(USER)
                time.sleep(1)
                _driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="loginPasswordInput"]').send_keys(PASS)
                time.sleep(1)
                _driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Loginbtn"]').click()

                time.sleep(5)
                if ">Account</span>" in _driver.page_source:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False

            def topcashback_click(_driver):
                try:
                    _driver.get('https://www.SITE.CO.UK/Earn.aspx?mpurl=shein&mpID=17233')
                    if "redirect.aspx?mpurl=shein" in _driver.current_url:
                        return _driver.current_url
                    else:
                        return False
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)

            if topcashback_login(driver):
                try:
                    print("--> LOGGED IN ...")

                    server = download_from_server()
                    data_from_server = server.split('|')

                    link = topcashback_click(driver)
                    print("--> LINK --> " + link)
                    time.sleep(4)

                    if link != driver.current_url:
                        print("--> LINK (REDIRECT) --> " + driver.current_url)
                        upload_to_server(urllib.parse.quote_plus(link),
                                         urllib.parse.quote_plus(
                                             driver.current_url.replace('https://www.example.com',
                                                                        data_from_server[0])),
                                         data_from_server[1])
                        # print(driver.current_url.replace('https://www.example.com', data_from_server[0]))
                        print("--> LINK UPLOADED TO THE DB ...")
                        # tear_down(driver)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
            else:
                print("--> ERROR --> DEBUG TIME ...")
                tear_down(driver)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        check_for_tasks()
        time.sleep(2)
```

It's the 2nd one I'm having trouble with, currently, with my code, I'm getting the error:

```
driver.get('https://www.example.com/logon')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I think this is because I'm not connecting the first browser window, instead it's opening a new one which fails with the error above straight away.

Is there possibly a way to keep the first browser open and reuse it? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: def init_driver(using_linux, proxy): may not be returning a driver.

Comment: Also it would be better to seperate that into it's own function. Your code has a bunch of functions which should seperate out or make check_for_tasks a class.

Comment: Checkout this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/72378446/11863448]