# How can I connect to a new window opened during a Chrome Session using C# Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working with Selenium in C# Visual Studio.

I'm able to open a Chrome browser session with no issue. However, when interacting with the webpage in that browser, I must click a link that opens a new window.

I must be able to connect to that newly opened browser window and interact with it.

Is there a way to identify all the open chrome sessions, and then connect to the browser that was opened by the click of the webpage link?

Just as an FYI, I can't just simply locate the link of the webpage that is opened up by the click of the link because there is JavaScript that is run when the link is clicked that control the data that appears in the new browser webpage.

If I simply open the link in a new tab in the exiting browser the page is empty so I must be able to interact with the newly opened browser.

Comment: Checkout this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/72378446/11863448] will help you

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I reviewed the link that you provided and the sublink within that thread. Based on a quick review this is showing how to re-use the browser that was initially opened by the chrome driver. In my process the Webpage is opening an entirely new browser. I'm hoping that someone out here has an insight on how to connect to this newly created browser. I'm going to see if I can figure it out based on the thread you referred me to. I'm just too inexperienced that I'm not sure I can.  Hopefully someone on here can help me out in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

If the additional browser tab or window is opened as part of the execution through the driver, the driver keeps a hold of those handles in the `driver.WindowHandles` collection.

The latest one should be the last in the collection.

You can swap control over the tab or window using the `driver.SwitchTo().Window()` method providing the handle name from the collection to it.

Pull this all together possibly as:

```cs
string newWindow = driver.WindowHandles.LastOrDefault();
driver.SwitchTo().Window(newWindow);
```